# How to stop resolved alert in google cloud stackdriver

Tags: google-cloud-platform, stackdriver, google-cloud-stackdriver, google-alerts

I am trying to setup an alert based on application errors. 
I am getting an open alert when it met the condition.
However, I don't want to receive the resolved alert for the same automatically. 
How to stop resolved alert in google cloud Stackdriver.

Comment: Do you mean that you only want to receive the alert once?

Comment: Yes, Brian. Only want to receive the alert once

Answer (score 2):

I understand that you want to discard the resolved alerts.

Here an example of an incident event and a resolved event [1]

It is not possible to discard the resolved event alert. For this case you have to filter those alerts on your own email. This is stated here [2]

[1] https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/alerts/incidents-events#inspecting_events

[2] https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/alerts/concepts-indepth#number-of-notifications