# Customize google cloud alerting

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-logging

I am using google cloud alerts to send emails in the event that a particular log is generated in google cloud logging. Now, the emails do arrive properly. But, every-time the cloud alert triggers, we receive two emails 1) alert firing 2) alert recovery. Can I somehow customize this behavior to get only one email?
Any leads will be helpful. If needed, I can describe the above situation in more detail.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to stop resolved alert in google cloud stackdriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61698380/how-to-stop-resolved-alert-in-google-cloud-stackdriver)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can deactivate notification (email in your case) on incident closure. You can do this using the Cloud Console.

1. Go to `Alerting` under `Monitoring` service
2. Click on the policy you want to modify
3. Click the `EDIT` button on top of the page
4. Click `NEXT` to land on `Who should be notified? (optional)`
5. Uncheck `Notify on incident closure` check box (as shown in green in
   the capture)
6. Click `SAVE`

[image]

Comment: Is there any way to automate this; either through gcloud cli or using python sdk?